# why would you want to declare a true false variable as type int?

Tags: java, boolean-expression, type-mismatch

The code below is from one of the classes in a SDK jar I'm using in my app.  How did it compile with int as the type for the indexSize, bestWidth, etc. below?

```
        config = this.mCamera.getParameters();
        int indexSize = false;
        int bestWidth = false;
        int bestHeight = false;
        int maxRes = false;
        ZZZCLog.d("Camera supported sizes");
        List<Size> supportedSizes = config.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        for(int i = supportedSizes.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            ZZZCLog.d(((Size)supportedSizes.get(i)).width + " " + ((Size)supportedSizes.get(i)).height + " aspect ratio: " + (double)((Size)supportedSizes.get(i)).width / (double)((Size)supportedSizes.get(i)).height);
        }

        config = this.mCamera.getParameters();
        ZZZCLog.d("Default preview size: " + config.getPreviewSize().width + "," + config.getPreviewSize().height);
        Size bestSize = this.getBestPreviewSize(config, width, height);
        int bestWidth = bestSize.width;
        int bestHeight = bestSize.height;
        ZZZCLog.d("Requesting preview size: " + bestWidth + "," + bestHeight);
        config.setPreviewSize(bestWidth, bestHeight);
        config.set("video-size", "" + bestWidth + "x" + bestHeight);
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the name of the Class with us?

Comment: You can't assign `false` to `int` in Java.

Comment: Are you sure it *did* compile like this? Is this decompiled code by any chance?

Comment: @thatotherguy The OP said "from one of the classes in a SDK **jar**", so it should be decompiled code.

Comment: perhaps the decompiler changed '0' to 'false'?

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the name of your decompiler tool? The only one info I have found is related to CFR Java Decompiler. You can see in the change history that they fixed many issues related this topic. For example: "Fix for boolean constant in attribute being treated as int (")", etc. URL: http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/

Comment: this isn't decompiled code.  It came in an example App SDK and runs perfectly fine.  I can't say whether or not this bit of code is actually accessed during my use of the app though.

Comment: @KentLauridsen Was this a `.java` file inside the jar? Does it compile for you?

Comment: @thatotherguy  I just downloaded the .zip file, extracted to a new folder, started Android Studio, went to the folder and selected the subfolder Example folder to build the project.  It runs from AS on my test phone, and when I look at the CameraThread.class as I'm going through the code to understand how the app works I came across what the code in question.

Comment: `CameraThread.class` is a compiled bytecode file. It does not contain source code. If you open a `.class` file and see Java code, it's been decompiled.

Comment: so it must be that the SDK was put together with some decompiled code.. and my compiler is capable of figuring out how to deal with the True and False variables as 1 and 0 ints?

Comment: @KentLauridsen No, I think you just don't have the real source code for the SDK. Find the source code from the SDK's web site (if available) and compare `CameraThread.java` to what your seeing. The code you're looking at is never compiled, it's just a human readable representation of the already-compiled binary file (a different tool might have shown hex or bytecode instead, but that's harder to read)

Comment: I guess it does come precompiled in the .jar so must get decompiled when extracting and loading into new project.  So my question is best answered by  @thatotherguy, that it's just poorly decompiled code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't trust decompiled Java code.

Internally, Java bytecode treats booleans as integers. You can compile this class:

```
class Test {
    public void foo() {
      boolean myBoolean = false;
    }
    public void bar() {
      int myInt = 0;
    }
}
```

And then examine the `javap -c Test` output:

```
public void foo();
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_1
   2: return

public void bar();
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_1
   2: return
```

As you can see, the `int` and `boolean` become the exact same code.

A decompiler will try its best to reconstruct valid source code from the stack based bytecode, but it's a hard problem even for unoptimized code with debug info, so it doesn't always get it right.