# In what version of Java did assigning false to an integer become invalid?

Tags: java, decompiling, legacy, legacy-code

I have the following legacy code from what looks to be a Java **1.1** library:

```java
int colon_index = false;

for(int i = 0; i < params_split.length; ++i) {
    int colon_index = params_split[i].indexOf(":");
    if (colon_index > 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It appears to be assigning `false` to a variable of type `int`. This is decompiled code, so it's also possible the IntelliJ decompiler has made a mistake.

I've checked release notes for old versions, but haven't been able to spot this change yet.

Assuming this was correct at some point in Java's history, **in what version of Java did this syntax stop being valid?**

Comment: Can you get the [bytecode](https://www.baeldung.com/java-class-view-bytecode) for the relevant part? Even if it were legit syntax, I seriously doubt someone would've initialized a variable named `index` with `false` even back in the 1.1 days.

Comment: Although the variable does act like a "pseudo boolean" more than an integer in the above code, so that could theoretically explain decompiler confusion I suppose.

Comment: Never, internally false is 0 (int). Bad decompiling.

Comment: I see. I posted a little snippet of bytecode below, as a comment to the accepted answer. Can you shed any light on what this is doing?

Comment: Assigning `false` to an `int` has always been illegal in Java.  It was illegal in Java 1.0.  (Don't be mislead by the bytecodes ... or the output of a dodgy decompiler!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trust decompiled code. Originally, it would've been `int colon_index = 0`

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569479/10376405) for more details.

Comment: I see. the bytecode for the assignment looks something like this: `LOCALVARIABLE colon_index I L9 L26 5`. Would anyone be able to explain what's going on here?

Comment: It seems one of the ten total L9 blocks in the bytecode for this class is: `L9 LINENUMBER 468 L9 ICONST_0 ISTORE 6` which looks plausible...