# Treating an integer as a boolean in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I'm working on updating an old Java application to work on modern operating systems and I've run into an error that I can't figure out. I don't have much experience with Java but from what I've read, you can't store boolean values in an integer (1 or 0) like in C++.

Here's the bit of code where the error is:

```
  public static double a(cr paramcr, int paramInt) {
    double d = 0.0D;
    int i = ++b;
    if (b <= l.length()) {
      if (paramInt < 0) {
        int j = b; // <----------- defined again as an integer.
        d = e();
        if (e == true && d >= h && d + f - g >= 1.0D && d + f - g <= d) {
          String str1 = String.valueOf((int)d);
          d = d + f - g;
          String str2 = String.valueOf((int)d);
          l = a(j, l, str1, str2, i);
        } else if (j == false) { // <---------------------------- error
          if (((d < 1.0D || d > d) ? false : true) == false)
            c = 7; 
        }
```

With error message:

```
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean
```

The variable j is defined as a static boolean at the top of the program, but later redefined as an integer inside of this 'a' class. I notice that there are other integer variables being used to compare to true and false statements in this class, but they are all being compared to some condition in order to get a true or false result. That's obviously not the case here, and my problem is that I can't think of a way that this program would have ever functioned in the past if this is how it was written. Any ideas as to why this could be or suggestions on my next move?

It doesn't help that none of this has any documentation or intuitive variable names.

Comment: that's the error you get? you don't declare variable e yet you use it. I'm surprised this bit doesn't cause errors: e == true because of the e

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, e is also a static boolean defined at the top of the file, it's just a really long file.

Comment: Is that decompiled obfuscated code? Because that would explain why you might get syntactically incorrect code. It would also explain the lack of documentation, the weird variable names and you having problems.

Comment: if (j == false ) while j is an int. how did you expect this to go well?

Comment: @Kayaman It is. I was sent some files that I was told contained the source code. It did not. I was then told to decompile it.

Comment: @Stultuske I mean I didn't write it, I was just tasked with fixing it. Apparently this worked at some point in time.

Comment: @Sam "this worked at some point in time". No, it didn't. if it did, check out what changed.

Comment: No, *that* code didn't work. The unobfuscated version worked. What you have is the version that's protected against "attackers" (in this case you). You'd have to clean it up by hand, then compile and hope it works. Then do the changes (remove copy protection, or whatever it is people these days do) and compile the "frankenstein" version.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `j` was defined at the top of the file or not. In the code you have `int j = b;`. This is creating a local variable which is hiding the previously defined static variable in that file. The `int j` is a complete separate reference from the `static boolean j`

Comment: @flakes I figured I would include that information in case it had some relevance to the error that I didn't know about.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569068/why-would-you-want-to-declare-a-true-false-variable-as-type-int

Answer (score 5):

In Java you cannot treat an `int` as a `boolean`.  Period.

> I was sent some files that I was told contained the source code. It did not. I was then told to decompile it.

What you are apparently looking at is some code that has been decompiled from a ".class" file.  Decompilation is NOT guaranteed to produce valid (compilable) Java source code.  And in this case, it appears that it hasn't.  Indeed, there are clues in that code that imply that the original bytecodes were *obfuscated* ... to *deliberately* make it hard for the decompiler to generate readable / valid Java source code.

(The problem is that the same bytecodes are used dealing with `boolean` and integer types up to `int`.  In this case, the decompiler has assumed that the local variable is an `int`, and not been able to figure out that its assumption was incorrect.  A better decompiler *might* be able to figure it out ...)

So what you will need to do is figure out how to modify that (not-really-Java) code to make it 1) compilable, and 2) do the correct thing<sup>1</sup>.

> It doesn't help that none of this has any documentation or intuitive variable names.

Well ... that what happens when you try to use decompiled code.  All local variable names and comments (including javadocs) are discarded by the compiler, and the decompiler has no way to reconstruct them.

The alternative is to go back to the people who were supposed to give you the source code and ask them to provide it to you ... for real!

---

<sup>1 - This assumes that you can figure out what this method is really supposed to be doing.  I don't think we can help you with that.  For a start, it would probably  be necessary to read the disassembled bytecodes to figure out what the code really does.</sup>

Comment: This is *obfuscated* code, not just decompiled code. It's *meant* to provide syntactically invalid source code on decompilation if possible. Sam is essentially the (very unlucky) blackhat here.

Comment: I guess the good part about getting roasted on StackOverflow is that I always learn a lot. I did contact them previously about this issue and was explicitly told to decompile it. I'm fairly certain that I'm not equipped to fix this thing in its current state, but I will be bringing it up again with the guy that tasked me with it.

Comment: @Sam either it contained the source code, or you had to decompile it. Yes, you are equipped with enough knowledge (if you know about scopes in Java) to fix this. there have been already hints as to what to do, and why this seems difficult.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not sensitive about it, it's just a reference to the running joke that the stack overflow community are generally pretty blunt in their opinions on questions. I'm still in school and I've never dealt with obfuscated code, so now I know.

Comment: @Sam If you can keep up that mind set, to learn from being roasted on StackOverflow, then you have a great tool for making a steep improvement with anything programming related. (No cynicism intended, honest expression of respect and attempt to cheer up and on.)

Answer (score 0):

"updating an old Java application to work on modern operating systems" already is nonsense. The operating system of a JAVA application is JAVA. "Platform independence" is core functionality of JAVA applications. I would refuse the task already at this point.

I really hate it when you can't use int like bool but it's not rocket science to replace "==false" by "==0" and "==true" by "!=0".